# Transparent .png from ggplot has white, aliased borders on text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a plot that's mostly transparent, but when I put it over dark backgrounds, an obvious white aliased border shows up. Here's the code:

```
ggplot(SHPS[which(SHPS$Gender!="Other"),], aes(x=Gender, y=P.mean, fill=Gender)) +
  geom_violin(color="grey40",lwd=.5, scale="area", width=.9) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1,color="grey40",lwd=.5, alpha=.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 5, 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#D9AEB8", "#AEC2D9"))+
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        axis.text=element_text(size=12, color="grey35"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14, color="grey35"),
        rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color="grey85"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color="grey90"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)) +
  ylab("Persistence Score")
ggsave("P-gender.png", width = 5, height = 5, bg = "transparent")
```

It would be a pain to create the dataset in a way that I can upload it here, so I'm hoping someone is able to spot the problem that's causing the following to happen when I place the resulting .png over a black background:

[image]

It's weird that it's only happening around text, and not other lines... It looks fine over a white background:
[image]

Is there some argument I could pass to ggsave that would fix this, or somewhere in the plot itself?

Comment: I've noticed this especially as I use ggplot2 and transparent png files in my xaringan slides. It happens especially as I PDF the slides. I'll be watching to see if you get any solid answers!

Comment: Try `fill = "black"` for `panel.background` and `plot.background` instead of transparent, this looks fine to me unless there's a specific reason you want transparent

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problem. When I use your code (but with a built-in dataset), I don't get the same white line problem - just grey text over a black background. Is there other `sessionInfo` that might be relevant?

Comment: @phalteman, I'm a bit of a beginner, where do I find sessionInfo and which parts should I look for?

Comment: You can find your sessionInfo by typing `sessionInfo()` in the console. I'm not sure what will be relevant but it might have to do with your package versions, your operating system, or something else that I haven't thought of. I am on a mac, running very current versions of all relevant packages. I'm not seeing the problem, so it's not something in your code itself...Just trying to play detective...

Comment: Using the option `type = cairo-png` in `ggsave()` was suggested as a solution that didn't work for me. (Neither does `antialias = "none"`). I solved the problem by saving in svg format and then converting by another program to png (or tiff). If the `svglight` package is available, you can use `type = svg` in the `ggsave()` function *or* use `dev.print(svg, ...)`.

Comment: @DavidO DUDE you solved my problem! Cairo-png worked! It was `type = "cairo-png"` but it worked perfectly.

Comment: @geedlet Really glad to hear! And I’m glad you caught my missing quotes!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (`"cairo-png"`). From user David O:

> Using the option `type = "cairo-png"` in `ggsave()` was suggested as a solution that didn't work for me. (Neither does `antialias = "none"`). I solved the problem by saving in svg format and then converting by another program to png (or tiff). If the `svglight` package is available, you can use `type = svg` in the `ggsave()` function or use `dev.print(svg, ...)`. – David O